# Flatten Directory but Preserve Directory Names in New Filename

Tags: find, rename

How can I flatten a directory in the following format?

Before: `./aaa/bbb/ccc.png`

After: `./aaa-bbb-ccc.png`

Comment: PS: Please also account for file names with odd characters (e.g. spaces)

Comment: You'll also need to specify how you want to handle the possible case where `./foo/bar/baz.png` and `./foo-bar-baz.png` both exist.  I assume you don't want to replace the latter with the former?

Comment: In my one case, it's irrelevant, but the answer should indeed account for that so others can rely on it! Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<sub>*Warning: I typed most of these commands directly in my browser. Caveat lector.*</sub>

With zsh and [zmv](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv):

```
zmv -o -i -Qn '(**/)(*)(D)' '${1//\//-}$2'
```

Explanation: The pattern `**/*` matches all files in subdirectories of the current directory, recursively (it doesn't match files in the current directory, but these don't need to be renamed). The first two pairs of parentheses are groups that can be refered to as `$1` and `$2` in the replacement text. The final pair of parentheses adds the `D` [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) so that dot files are not omitted. `-o -i` means to pass the `-i` option to `mv` so that you are prompted if an existing file would be overwritten.

---

With only POSIX tools:

```
find . -depth -exec sh -c '
    for source; do
      case $source in ./*/*)
        target="$(printf %sz "${source#./}" | tr / -)";
        mv -i -- "$source" "${target%z}";;
      esac
    done
' _ {} +
```

Explanation: the `case` statement omits the current directory and top-level subdirectories of the current directory. `target` contains the source file name (`$0`) with the leading `./` stripped and all slashes replaced by dashes, plus a final `z`. The final `z` is there in case the filename ends with a newline: otherwise the command substitution would strip it.

If your `find` doesn't support `-exec … +` (OpenBSD, I'm looking at you):

```
find . -depth -exec sh -c '
    case $0 in ./*/*)
      target="$(printf %sz "${0#./}" | tr / -)";
      mv -i -- "$0" "${target%z}";;
    esac
' {} \;
```

---

With bash (or ksh93), you don't need to call an external command to replace the slashes by dashes, you can use the ksh93 parameter expansion with string replacement construct `${VAR//STRING/REPLACEMENT}`:

```
find . -depth -exec bash -c '
    for source; do
      case $source in ./*/*)
        source=${source#./}
        target="${source//\//-}";
        mv -i -- "$source" "$target";;
      esac
    done
' _ {} +
```

Comment: The `for source` examples miss the first presented file/dir... I've finally found out why you (normally) have used `_` as `$0` :) ... and thanks for the great answers. I learn so much from them.

Comment: Note that the zmv example just does a dry run: it prints out the move commandsbut it doesn't execute them. To actually execute those commands, remove the n in -Qn.

Answer (score 11):

While there are good answers already here, I find this more intuitive, within `bash`:

```
find aaa -type f -exec sh -c 'new=$(echo "{}" | tr "/" "-" | tr " " "_"); mv "{}" "$new"' \;
```

Where `aaa` is your existing directory.  The files it contains will be moved to the current directory (leaving only empty directories in aaa).  The two calls to `tr` handle both directories and spaces (without logic for escaped slashes - an exercise for the reader).

I consider this more intuitive and relatively easy to tweak.  I.e. I could change the `find` parameters if say I want to find only .png files.  I can change the `tr` calls, or add more as needed.  And I can add `echo` before `mv` if I want to visually check that it will do the right thing (then repeat without the extra `echo` only if things look right:

```
find aaa -name \*.png -exec sh -c 'new=$(echo "{}" | tr "/" "-" | tr " " "_"); echo mv "{}" "$new"' \;
```

Note also I'm using `find aaa`... and not `find .`... or `find aaa/`... as the latter two would leave funny artifacts in the final file name.

Comment: Thanks for this one liner - this worked well for me when I did it from outside of the directory (which is exactly what you said to do). 

When I tried to do from inside the directory (hoping to avoid the root directory name being added) all of the files "disappeared". I had turned them into hidden files in that same directory.

Comment: I like this one better and easier to understand. `find` with `-exec` makes things so much cleaner.

Answer (score 4):

```
find . -mindepth 2 -type f -name '*' |
  perl -l000ne 'print $_;  s/\//-/g; s/^\.-/.\// and print' |
    xargs -0n2 mv
```

Note: this will not work for filename which contain `\n`.
This, of course only moves type `f` files...
The only name clashes would be from files pre-existing in the *pwd*

Tested with this basic subset

```
rm -fr junk
rm -f  junk*hello*

mkdir -p  junk/junkier/junkiest
touch    'hello    hello'
touch    'junk/hello    hello'
touch    'junk/junkier/hello    hello'
touch    'junk/junkier/junkiest/hello    hello'
```

Resulting in

```
./hello    hello
./junk-hello    hello
./junk-junkier-hello    hello
./junk-junkier-junkiest-hello    hello
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `ls` version.. comments welcome. It works for whacky filenames like this 
`"j1ळ\n\001\n/j2/j3/j4/\nh  h\n"`, but I am really interested to know of any pitfalls. It is more of an exercise in "can the maligned `ls` actually do it (robustly)?"

```
ls -AbQR1p * |                        # paths in "quoted" \escaped format
    sed -n '/":$/,${/.[^/]$/p}' |     # skip files in pwd, blank and dir/ lines
    { bwd="$PWD"; while read -n1;     # save base dir strip leading "quote
                        read -r p; do # read path
        printf -vs "${p%\"*}"         # strip trailing quote"(:)
        [[ $p == *: ]] && {           # this is a directory
            cd   "$bwd/$s"            # change into new directory
            rnp="${s//\//-}"-         # relative name prefix
        } || mv "$s" "$bwd/$rnp$s"
      done; }
```

Answer (score -1):

Just pipe the filename + path to `tr` command. `tr <replace> <with>`

```sh
for FILE in `find aaa -name "*.png"`
do
  NEWFILE=`echo $FILE | tr '/' '-'`
  cp -v $FILE $NEWFILE
done
```

Comment: This doesn't handle odd filenames safely.  Spaces will break it (among other things).

Comment: On first glance, this is a clean, readable solution but @jw013 is right, it won't handle spaces well. Would changing the `cp` line to `cp -v "$FILE" "$NEWFILE"` help?  (Also, you should not assume only png files.)

Comment: @NathanJ.Brauer Adding quotes to the `cp` line is insufficient.  The entire approach of parsing `find` output with a `for` loop is flawed.  The only safe ways to use `find` are with `-exec`, or `-print0` if available (less portable than `-exec`).  I'd suggest a more robust alternative but your question is under-specified at the moment.

Answer (score -2):

Safe for spaces in filenames:

```
#!/bin/bash

/bin/find $PWD -type f | while read FILE
do
    _new="${FILE//\//-}"
    _new="${_new:1}"
    #echo $FILE
    #echo $_new

    /bin/mv "$FILE" "$_new"
done
```

Ran mine with `cp` instead of `mv` for obvious reasons, but should produce the same.

Comment: `type find` -> `find is /usr/bin/find` on my machine. Using `PATH` as a variable name in a script is a terrible idea. Also, your script mangles file names with spaces or backslashes, because you misuse the `read` command (search this site for `IFS read -r`).

Comment: `find is hashed (/bin/find)`, relevant how? Different distros are different?

Comment: Knew I should have stayed away from this, vulture bait.

Comment: @Tim You can always delete the answer to get your rep back (and mine as well b/c it costs rep to downvote).  Hard-coding paths into scripts seems to suggest that you are missing the point of the `PATH` environment variable, which is something *every* Unix system uses.  If you write `/bin/find` then your script is actually broken on every system (Gilles, mine, and probably the OP's) that doesn't have `/bin/find` (e.g. b/c it is in `/usr/bin/find`).  The whole point of the `PATH` environment variable is to make this a non-issue.

Comment: By the way, `$(pwd)` is already available in a variable: `$PWD`. But you must **not** use an absolute path here: if your script is invoked from, say, `/home/tim`, it attempts to rename `/home/tim/some/path` to `/home-tim-some-path`.

Comment: Woops forgot about system wide $PATH variable. Best part is I was like "Huuur why do I need to hardcode these paths".